# How to execute when someone is wearing specific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make Thor's hammer and armor, but I need to execute when someone is wearing Thor's armor, because i am trying to do lightning when someone kills 10 entities and i want only with Thor's armor and hammer could "rage" (make lightning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the armor items a custom item tag so that they're easy to detect and impossible to fake:

```
give @p iron_chestplate 1 0 {thorArmor:1b,display:{Name:"Thor's Chestplate"},Unbreakable:1b}
```

Then whenever you want to do something with players who are wearing the armor, run these commands:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[tag=wearingThorChest] remove wearingThorChest
scoreboard players tag @a add wearingThorChest {Inventory:[{Slot:102b,tag:{thorArmor:1b}}]}
say @a[tag=wearingThorChest] is/are wearing Thor's Chestplate!
```

`102b` is the chest armor slot. You can find the other slot numbers on the Wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Inventory_slot_numbers

You can do something similar with the mainhand item:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[tag=holdingMjolnir] remove holdingMjolnir
scoreboard players tag @a add holdingMjolnir {SelectedItem:{tag:{thorHammer:1b}}}
say @a[tag=holdingMjolnir] is/are holding Mjolnir!
```

Answer (score 0):

This command tests for all players wearing a diamond helmet called "Thor's helmet" and a diamond chestplate called "Thor's chestplate":

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{Slot:103,id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Thor's helmet"}}},{Slot:102,id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Thor's chestplate"}}}]}
```

It this doesn't work, please tell me, then I can fix it. Currently I'm not on my PC, so I can't test it.

Comment: Apparently I had this tab open for a very long time, I didn't see the already accepted answer when I wrote mine. The other answer is better than mine.